# POSTing Form Fields with same Name Attribute

Tags: php, post

If you have a form containing text inputs with duplicate `name` attributes, and the form is posted, will you still be able to obtain the values of all fields from the `$_POST` array in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple inputs with same name through POST in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880619/multiple-inputs-with-same-name-through-post-in-php)

Comment: This question is much older than the suggested duplicate, and has more answers. Surely that one is a duplicate of this?

Comment: Current consensus is to close by "quality": <http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha> Since "quality" is not measurable, I just go by upvotes. ;-) Likely it comes down to which question hit the best newb Google keywords on the title.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

No. Only the last input element will be available.

If you want multiple inputs with the same name use `name="foo[]"` for the input name attribute. `$_POST` will then contain an array for foo with all values from the input elements.

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="a[]" value="foo"/>
    <input name="a[]" value="bar"/>
    <input name="a[]" value="baz"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

See the [HTML reference at Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/name).

The reason why `$_POST` will only contain the last value if you don't use `[]` is because PHP will basically just explode and foreach over the raw query string to populate `$_POST`. When it encounters a name/value pair that already exists, it will overwrite the previous one.

However, you can still access the raw query string like this:

```
$rawQueryString = file_get_contents('php://input'))
```

Assuming you have a form like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="foo"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="bar"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="baz"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

the $`rawQueryString` will then contain `a=foo&a=bar&a=baz`.

You can then use your own logic to parse this into an array. A naive approach would be

```
$post = array();
foreach (explode('&', file_get_contents('php://input')) as $keyValuePair) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $keyValuePair);
    $post[$key][] = $value;
}
```

which would then give you an array of arrays for each name in the query string.

Comment: ok cool, so each input with a duplicate name should just be name="foo[]"? Not name="foo[0]" or anything?

Comment: @danwellman Just `foo[]` will do but you can also use `foo[0]`, `foo[bar]` and even `foo[bar][baz]`. Just try the various combinations on your webserver to see how they arrive in $_POST.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `name="nfo[val]"` just use `name="nfo[val][]"` and in PHP you can use a `foreach()`

HTML code:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="nfo[val][]" value="val1"/>
    <input name="nfo[val][]" value="val2"/>
    <input name="nfo[val][]" value="val3"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
$output='';
foreach ($nfo['val'] as $key=>$val) {
    $output.= $val.", ";
}
```

`$output` will be: `val1, val2, val3`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer because I thought you'd have to quote val in the html form. [val] can be a string or integer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You have to create an array of them:
with `name=inputname[]`
and get with post,request or get

```
$inputs = $_POST['inputname'];

print_r($inputs);
```

Answer (score 2):

Only if the name are array-typed `names[]` in that case you will be getting an array as the variable in the $_POST variable.