# add form in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hello i've got a form like that

```
<form action="xx.php">
  <div id="myForm">
  </div>
  <button>Add Form</button>
  <div id="clone">
  </div>
</form>
```

And when a user click on "Add form", "myForm" is cloned into "clone".
I would know why where the form is submitted, i can reach only the input form "myForm" and not the input of the cloned form (into xx.php). Is it because the cloned form is created by javascrpt ?

Comment: Does it have the same 'name' attributes?

Comment: The cloned form is nested within the original form, that's not a good thing. Move the `<div id="clone"></div>` to sit outside of the original form and it might solve your problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really "cloning" the form, you are also cloning the 'name' attributes I guess, after submitting that won't work as discussed in this question: [POSTing Form Fields with same Name Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203430/posting-form-fields-with-same-name-attribute)

Comment: @ kaljak In fact the name attribute are not the same (i not really cloning the form, i create a new form with same input, but different name)

Comment: can you provide the whole form you are wanting to submit?