# Trying to post a form with multiple fields with same name as an array

Tags: php, html, post

I am trying to post a form with fields that act like a table entries

I think it would be best if I give an example:

```
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="appsDetails[name]" placeholder="Enter name" value=""/></td>
            <td><label>ID:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="appsDetails[id]" placeholder="Enter id" value=""/></td>
            <td><label>Token:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="appsDetails[token]" placeholder="Enter token" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td><label>Name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="appsDetails[name]" placeholder="Enter name" value=""/></td>
            <td><label>ID:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="appsDetails[id]" placeholder="Enter id" value=""/></td>
            <td><label>Token:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="appsDetails[token]" placeholder="Enter token" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td><label>Name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="appsDetails[name]" placeholder="Enter name" value=""/></td>
            <td><label>ID:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="appsDetails[id]" placeholder="Enter id" value=""/></td>
            <td><label>Token:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="appsDetails[token]" placeholder="Enter token" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        
        
    </table>
</form>
```

You can also check: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/c6zGx/)

When the above example get submitted I only get the last row in the table.

My question: Is there a way to do it like array within array? If that make sense

I am trying to avoid doing something like name[]. id[], token[].

Comment: Manually enumerate them group-wise with `value=apps[2][token]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203430/posting-form-fields-with-same-name-attribute?rq=1

Comment: vincent This will only work for 1D array.

Comment: what if you use appsDetails[][name] like my answer, or do I miss the point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can, simply use an empty [], everytime this one is encountered, it is considered as a new sibling

```
<tr>
            <td><label>Name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="appsDetails[][name]" placeholder="Enter name" value=""/></td>
            <td><label>ID:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="appsDetails[][id]" placeholder="Enter id" value=""/></td>
            <td><label>Token:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="appsDetails[][token]" placeholder="Enter token" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
```