# How to Prevent Form Data From Posting

Tags: html

What HTML attribute will prevent form data from posting if two inputs have the same `name` attribute?

```
<form>
<select name="amount">
  <option value="100">$100</option>
  <option value="50">$50</option>
  <option value="10">$10</option>
  <option value="1">$1</option>
</select>
Other: <input type="text" name="amount">
</form>
```

**Edit:**
The reason I need two with the same name value is I'm using the `jQuery` to show() and hide() functions for a select and input.

Comment: The `disabled` attribute comes to mind.

Comment: why not just use 2 different names and then set your variable to the text one if it isn't empty

Comment: I've tried both `disable` and `read-only` with no success. The reason I need two with the same name value is I'm using `jQuery` to show() and hide() functions for a select and input.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such HTML attribute. It's perfectly legal for two elements to have the same name, and both values will be included in the data that is posted.

The values will be sent as two separate items, so the posted data from the form in the question could for example look like this:

```
amount=10&amount=42
```

Comment: How can I pull it into PHP separately? `$_POST['amount[1]']`?

Comment: @Conor: If you can use the name `amount[]` instead of `amount` in the HTML code, then PHP will return them as an array from `$_POST['amount']`. If not, then you can read them from `php://input`. Here are some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2203456/69083