# In Laravel 5.1 Can't post value of checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.1

I have 2 checkboxs inside a form, I can't post value of them.
I have already tried this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label class="col-md-6" for="invoiced">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="invoiced" value="false" name="project[invoiced]"> 
                     Invoiced </label>
                <label class="col-md-6" for="tobeinvoiced">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tobeinvoiced" value="true" name="project[tobeinvoiced]" checked> 
                    To be Invoiced </label>
            </div>
```

with this script that changes the value of 2 checkboxes in true or false:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('#tobeinvoiced').change(function(){
                cb = $(this);
                cb.val(cb.prop('checked'));
            });
            $('#invoiced').change(function(){
                cb = $(this);
                cb.val(cb.prop('checked'));
            });
            </script>
```

but when I submit, the values passed are set to null.

Comment: so you want to send the value of the check box? does else other form elements works fine?

Comment: Yes, all other input (text, date, number) works fine, but the value of checkboxs are null!

Comment: Unchecked checkbox is not send at the request as parameter.  If it exists at the request that means that the checkbox is marked else its not marked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem, this is the link : [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098834/make-checkbox-return-false-when-unchecked).

My code became:

```
<label class="col-md-6" for="invoiced">
   <input type="checkbox" key="invoiced"/>
   <input type="hidden" id="invoiced" value="0" name="project[invoiced]"> 
   Invoiced </label>
<label class="col-md-6" for="tobeinvoiced">
   <input type="checkbox" key="tobeinvoiced" checked/>
   <input type="hidden" id="tobeinvoiced" value="1" name="project[tobeinvoiced]"> 
   To be Invoiced </label>
```

with this script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $('[key]').change(function () {
                    var key = $(this).attr('key');
                    $($('[name="project[' + key + ']"]')).val($(this).is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false');
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$project = $request->input('project');
$tobeinvoiced = $project['tobeinvoiced'];
```

Basically the naming convention you are using makes it an array and you cant call an array directly in request input in laravel

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've forgotten to mention I'm using Json enctype, so with Input::get('project') I can get all values for input, so everything works a part for checkboxes value.