# I cant ajax post checkbox value in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.1

I have many checkbox and other input like text,select ,textarea ,... in my form
I post all data of inputs but checkbox not post data
I saw this link
  [In Laravel 5.1 Can't post value of checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466411/in-laravel-5-1-cant-post-value-of-checkbox)
But I do not want to use hidden button
Is there another way ?????
My form

```
 <form id='test-form'>
 <input name='text1'>
 <input name='text2'>
 <textarea name='text3'></textarea>
 <input   type="checkbox" name="test1"    >
 <input   type="checkbox" name="test2"    >
 <input   type="checkbox" name="test3"    >
 <input   type="checkbox" name="test4"    >
 <input  type="checkbox" name="test5"    >
 <input   type="checkbox" name="test6"    >
 <input type="button" id='send'>
 </form> 
 <script>
 $(document).on("click", "#send", function () {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
        url: 'add',
        data: $("#test-form").serialize(),
       success: function (result) {
            $('#ajax_div').html(result);
       },
   })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Why can't you? Any error in your code? You should provide more infos if you want to be helped out

Comment: thanks i post all inputs like selecet , text ,... but the check box not pass data

Comment: In that link use hidden button but I want use hidden button because i have a lot of checkbox

Comment: Could you please post the code you're using?? How can we help otherwise?? guessing? free code?

Comment: I edit post and send form and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkboxes will not send any data because they do not have the `value` attribute.

Change your html to:

```
 <input   type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="1"   >
 <input   type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="2"   >
 <input   type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="3"  >
 <input   type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="4"   >
 <input  type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="5"  >
 <input   type="checkbox" name="test[]"   value="6"  >
 <input type="button" id='send'>
```

Note that I also changed the names to `test[]`, this will send an array of all the checkboxes that are checked.

For example: I check checkbox 1 and checkbox 3, the value that the server will receive is in `$_REQUEST['test']` (either POST or GET), and will be an array with content `[1,3]`.

If none of the checkboxes is marked, the `$_REQUEST['test']` will be not set which you can check server side using `isset()`.