# Multiple rows of radio buttons, only gets the value of the last row

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter

I have rows with a dynamic radio buttons for each. This is how it looks on the view part
initial value of each row shows the current one saved on the database

[image]

I've been trying to make the update button work whenever a user wants to update one's status (per row), I'm not making any progress.

The code on the view part is as follows:

```
if ($row['STATUS'] == 'Active') {
                    echo "<td>
                            <input type='radio' value='Active' name='status' id='status' checked/><label>Active</label>
                            <input type='radio' value='Inactive' name='status' id='status' /><label>Inactive</label>    
                    ";
} else {
    echo "<td>
            <input type='radio' value='Active' name='status' id='status' /><label>Active</label>
            <input type='radio' value='Inactive' name='status' id='status' checked/><label>Inactive</label>";   
}
```

Please note that the code above is inside a foreach loop. I'm starting to think that this foreach loop has someething to do on why it only gets the last value returned by the result_array().

I even tried using JavaScript on the view part for the values of the radio buttons, but I can't seem to make it work as well.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POSTing Form Fields with same Name Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203430/posting-form-fields-with-same-name-attribute)

Comment: `id='status'` is the culprit here. Use class instead

Comment: Sorry about that. I already did something like this for the name attribute to avoid duplicates of the form fields `name='status".$row['ID']."`, I was able to get the values shown, however, I wanted the update button work when the user decides to change the value via the radio buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you want to get multiple values of formdata with same name then you have to change name as name[]

**Try code as shown below**

```
if ($row['STATUS'] == 'Active') {
    echo "<td>
<input type='radio' value='Active' name='status[]' class='status' checked/><label>Active</label>
<input type='radio' value='Inactive' name='status[]' class='status' /><label>Inactive</label>    
";
} else {
    echo "<td>
<input type='radio' value='Active' name='status[]' class='status' /><label>Active</label>
<input type='radio' value='Inactive' name='status[]' class='status' checked/><label>Inactive</label>";   
}
```

Comment: @Neil if answer is useful then mark answer as useful and closed this question ......

Comment: sorry about that, I've already marked it as useful. Again, thanks!