# HTML how to add unique input element on button click

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

Hi I am trying to figure out how to add input element on button click using plain javascript to be used latter for sending data to backend.

```
<div class="myDiv">
<input type="text" id="inputData" name="selectOption">
        <select id="optionData">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
<div class="myDiv">

<input type="button" value="Add element" onclick="AddElement()">
```

I would be using that to send data to the backend.
The only approach that I could think of was declare a global javascript array and use it to store it

```
var elements = [];
function AddElement() {
  const inputData = document.getElementById("inputData").value;
  const optionData = document.getElementById("optionData").value;
  const data = {
    inputData: inputData,
    optionData: optionData
  };
  elements.push(data);
  // create new element in dom with the data and random ids and clear the inputData and optionData element.
}
```

The problem with the above is that changes to existing element would not reflect in the global array.

Could someone suggest a better approach?

Comment: _“I would be using that to send data to the backend.”_ - why would that need any IDs in the first place? _“Could someone suggest a better approach?”_ - elements can be selected in a multitude of different ways, it does not always have to be by ID. So explain what they are actually needed for in the first.

Comment: you can use array input , refere https://stackoverflow.com/a/42293411/6309457

Comment: @CBroe unique id is not required, just simple way to add elements on button click that could be latter used for sending data on backend

Comment: Then I don’t get what the actual question is supposed to be here.

Comment: The current implementation would not reflect the changes on updated made to the already added element

Comment: You got me a bit censused also, What will you be using to send data to back-end, PHP or JS? Is this part of HTML form?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit uncleaner how will you send data to server etc and I see there is some confusion on technique how to achieve this. So I will cover two scenarios. Both will make new input fields out of your initial `select` and `input` as requested and additionally quid how to send them to server.

I will not make unique `ids` or `name` attributes on those fields because that would mean you would need to know in front what `ids` or `names` are generated and fetch them on server side on submit, instead when submitting a form using HTML and PHP, we will make `array` with `input names` attribute. Case with JS sending data to server will be similar using arrays.

**First way using PHP and setting form inputs names as array:**

1 - Create a form below your input and select

```
<form id="result">
...
</form>
```

2 - On click of button, save data into variable like you did, then clear those fields:

```
document.getElementById("inputData").value="";
document.getElementById("optionData").value="";
```

3 - Then create two input fields, fill them with data and append them into form:

```
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML +=
 '<input type="text"  name="inputData[]" value="'+inputData+'">
<input type="text"  name="optionData[]" value="'+optionData+'"><br>';
```

4 - One of the input fields will have `name="inputData[]`" other will have `name="optionData[]"`. Notice the `[]` sign, that will on form submit create on array. Then or server side for example with PHP you catch that array and use `foreach()` to send them to server as `keys` and `values`.
Please read more about this here:
[Posting Form Fields with same Name Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203430/posting-form-fields-with-same-name-attribute)

**EXAMPLE SNIPPET:**

```js
var elements = [];

function AddElement() {
  const inputData = document.getElementById("inputData").value;
  const optionData = document.getElementById("optionData").value;
  
  // create new element in dom with the data and random ids and clear the inputData and optionData element.

  document.getElementById("inputData").value="";
  document.getElementById("optionData").value="";
  //clear the inputData and optionData element.
  
  document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML += '<input type="text"  name="inputData[]" value="'+inputData+'"><input type="text"  name="optionData[]" value="'+optionData+'"><br>';
  // add new line with 2 inputs, one is inputData other is optionData

}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <input type="text" id="inputData" name="selectOption">
  <select id="optionData">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
<form id="result">


</form>

  <input type="button" value="Add element" onclick="AddElement()">
</div>
```

Sending data with JS can be done in multiple ways.
You could use above HTML markup and then catch all form data like this:

```
//EXAMPLE USING JS TO GET FORM DATA
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#result'))
console.clear()
for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ' - ' + pair[1]); 
    // here you could send AJAX data to server for each entry 
}
```

Please read more about how to [How can I get form data with JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/how-can-i-get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery)

**SNIPPET EXAMPLE:**

```js
var elements = [];

function AddElement() {
  const inputData = document.getElementById("inputData").value;
  const optionData = document.getElementById("optionData").value;
  
  // create new element in dom with the data and random ids and clear the inputData and optionData element.

  document.getElementById("inputData").value="";
  document.getElementById("optionData").value="";
  //clear the inputData and optionData element.
  
  document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML += '<input type="text"  name="inputData" value="'+inputData+'"><input type="text"  name="optionData" value="'+optionData+'"><br>';
  // add new line with 2 inputs, one is inputData other is optionData

//EXAMPLE USING JS TO GET FORM DATA
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#result'))
console.clear()
for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ' - ' + pair[1]); 
    // here you could send AJAX data to server for each entry 
}

}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <input type="text" id="inputData" name="selectOption">
  <select id="optionData">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
<form id="result">


</form>

  <input type="button" value="Add element" onclick="AddElement()">
</div>
```

Or you could like you intended save them into arrays on initial creation per each row and send items using AJAX without even using HTML form.

**AND TO answer the question** how to create unique ids, names or classes:
Declare `i` variable as number `0` outside of click function:

```
i="0";
//set initial unique number i
```

then inside click call it like this `++i` this will result in `optionData1`, `optionData2` etc  on every `++i` initiation:

```
name="optionData'+(++i)+'"
```

you can use it on ids, classes or anything:

```
id="newId'+(++i)+'"
```

`newid1`, `newid2` etc...

But like i said, you cant really generate unique ids or anything because you can not program them in front to use them to send fields to server.

**Example:**

```js
var elements = [];

i = "0";
//set initial uniqe number i

function AddElement() {
  const inputData = document.getElementById("inputData").value;
  const optionData = document.getElementById("optionData").value;

  // create new element in dom with the data and random ids and clear the inputData and optionData element.

  document.getElementById("inputData").value = "";
  document.getElementById("optionData").value = "";
  //clear the inputData and optionData element.

  document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML += '<input type="text"  name="inputData' + (++i) + '" value="' + inputData + '"><input type="text"  name="optionData' + (++i) + '" value="' + optionData + '"><br>';
  // add new line with 2 inputs, one is inputData other is optionData
  // use ++i to generate last number plus, and just add it to some name, id or class; name="optionData'+(++i)+'"
  
  console.clear();
  [...document.querySelectorAll('#result > input')].forEach(input => {
      console.log(input.getAttribute("name"));      
    })
  }
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <input type="text" id="inputData" name="selectOption">
  <select id="optionData">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <form id="result">


  </form>

  <input type="button" value="Add element" onclick="AddElement()">
</div>
```